# How can I get the true position of a Khepera Differential Wheels in Webots 6.4.1 Pro?

Tags: webots

Is it possible to add a GPS node?  That seems like it would be the simplest answer.

I've also made some progress in creating a supervisor, but how can I get the supervisor controller and the differential wheels controller to run at the same time?

I need to get the true position every few seconds in order to trace its path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scene tree, click on children, then add new, select GPS node.
Save and refresh webots.

To activate and access the gps values:

```
gps = wb_robot_get_device('gps')
wb_gps_enable(gps, 10) % read every 10 milliseconds.
wb_gps_get_values(gps)
```